# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Membership/user/' is not allowed

Tags: wcf, silverlight, entity-framework

This code:

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 user temp = new user();
 temp.Username = UserName.Text;
 temp.Password = Password.Text;
 dataBase.AddTouser(temp);
 IAsyncResult result = dataBase.BeginSaveChanges(new AsyncCallback (OnSaveChangesCompleted), temp); 
}

void OnSaveChangesCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
 try
 {   
    string name = ((user) result.AsyncState).Username.ToString();
    dataBase.EndSaveChanges(result);
 }
 catch (DataServiceRequestException ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("OnSaveChangesCompleted Error: " + ex.ToString());
 }
}
```

produces this error:

The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Membership/user/' is not allowed

I think it may have something to do with this being incorrect:

```
public static void InitializeService(IDataServiceConfiguration config)
{
 config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
 config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
}
```

Or it may have something to do with the ASP.NET configuration, but I am not sure what to do in there.

I am trying to use Silverlight, DataEntityFramework, and a WCF Service all together (for the first time) and have no idea where exactly the solution to this problem lies.

Comment: Please format your code so that people can read it.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem, it seems that there are problems with the url rewriting.

http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2007/01/05/aspnet-the-http-verb-post-used-to-access-path-is-not-allowed/

You have to remove  the mapping of ‘*’ to aspnet_isapi.dll in yourIIS settings.